# How do I synchronize background music and buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

An application writes. Music plays on the background of the application. And I want to stop and resume this music from every page of the application

But after pressing the music stop button on one page, the buttons on the other pages do not change.

And when I go back to the first page, the music starts all over again.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Music {

    static var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
    enum SoundEffect {
        case background
    }

    static func playSound(effect : SoundEffect) {

        var soundFileName = ""
        switch effect {
            case.background:
                soundFileName = "background"
        }

        let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFileName, ofType: "wav")
        guard bundlePath != nil else {
            print("Couldn't find sound file \(soundFileName) in the bundle")
            return
        }

        do {
            let soudURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)

            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soudURL)
            audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al first check AVAudioPlayer is already initialize or not and after that check player is playing or stop.

```
if let audioPlayer = Music.audioPlayer, audioPlayer.playing {
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```